# DTO mapping using interface

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, mvvm

[EDIT] Before reading, I have managed to solve this by simply casting the different data classes.
I have updated the code with what works but you are all welcome with tips!

Dear stackoverflow users,

I'd like to start off by saying that I understand that the question is most likely going to be relatable to Automapper.
Unfortunately... NuGet is, for some reason, not willing to install Automapper.
So instead I decided to try my shot at writing a manual mapper between DTO's and entities.
I am kinda new to IoC and DI which I am guessing is the main reason to why my implementation is incorrect.

Basically I have 5+ different datagrids, where all of them are linked to different tables and therefor have different structures.
However, they all have the exact same message handlers that points to the same methods in the viewmodel that will take care of adding, deleting and modifying.

The code that handles deleting looks like this.

In the viewmodel:

```
 public void KeyDown(EventArgs eventArgs, object sourceSender)
    {
        var dataGridContext = sourceSender as DataGrid;
        var keyEventArgs = eventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
        if (keyEventArgs == null) return;
        switch (keyEventArgs.Key)
        {
            case Key.Delete:
                if (dataGridContext != null)
                        foreach (var selectedEntity in dataGridContext.SelectedItems.OfType<IEntityObject>())
                        {
                            _mainModel.DeletePendingEntityObject(selectedEntity);
                        }
                break;
        }
    }
```

In the model:

```
    public void DeletePendingEntityObject<TEntity>(TEntity sender) where TEntity : IEntityObject
    {
         if (sender.State == EntityState.Added)
         {
             _pendingEntityObjects.Remove(sender);
             return;
         }
         AddPendingEntityObject(sender, EntityState.Deleted);
    }
```

And the code that handles adding and modifying looks like this:

In the viewmodel:

```
 public void RowEditEnding(object sender)
    {
        var dataGridContext = sender as DataGrid;
        if (_isNewItem && dataGridContext != null)
        {
            var item = dataGridContext.CurrentItem as IEntityObject;
            _mainModel.AddPendingEntityObject(item, EntityState.Added);
            _isNewItem = false;
        }

        else if (dataGridContext != null)
        {
            var item = dataGridContext.CurrentItem as IEntityObject;
            if (item == null) return;
            _mainModel.AddPendingEntityObject(item, EntityState.Modified);
        }
    }
```

In the model:

```
    public void AddPendingEntityObject<TEntity>(TEntity sender,
 EntityState entityState) where TEntity : IEntityObject
    {
        sender.State = entityState;
        _pendingEntityObjects.Add(sender);
    }
```

Now, all of this works perfectly until I wanted to create a mapper that would map the DTO objects to their entities to save it to the database.
I believe the implementation is incorrect because I will have to add every property in the interface that I'd like to be mappable in the DtoMapper.cs (shown below). Which ends up in all of DTO's having variables that are not related to them whatsoever.

This is my try at it:

```
 foreach (var item in _pendingEntityObjects)
            {
                using (var context = new CentralEntities())
                {
                    var entityObj = new DtoMapper<IEntityObject>(item);
                    context.Entry(entityObj.TranslatedObj).State = item.State;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

This is what the DtoMapper.cs looks like:

```
    public DtoMapper(T t)
    {
        if (t.GetType() == typeof(Table1Dto))
        {
            var table1Obj = t as Table1Dto;
            if(table1Obj != null)
            TranslatedObj = new table_1
            {
                id = table2Obj.Id,
                table1Code = table1Obj.Table1Code,
                reference = table1Obj.Reference
            };
        }
        else if (t.GetType() == typeof (Table2Dto))
        {
            var table2Obj = t as Table2Dto;
            if(table2Obj != null)
            TranslatedObj = new table_2
            {
                id = table2Obj.Id,
                table2Code = table2Obj.Table2Code,
                reference = table2Obj.Reference
            };
        }
    }

    public object TranslatedObj { get; set; }
```

How would I solve this to keep code clean and generic methods/mapper that would work with any datagrid?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check the abstract factory design pattern. You should create a factory to resolve your mappers for your generic T type DTOs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern